# How to make a multiple copies of a single script and run parallely?

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing

I have a mongodb collection with 2 million documents. There is a single script to process them and it run on aws. But in between the processing of those url I get segmentation fault that means my system ran out of memory.

I am thinking to call in batch size of 10 000 from mongodb and assigning them to a particular script.

I am not able to find a proper documentation in order to move forward on this.